# Check the tf-idf scores of sklearn in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am following the example [here](https://janav.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/tf-idf-and-cosine-similarity/) to calculate the TF-IDF values using sklearn.

My code is as follows.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
myvocabulary = ['life', 'learning']
corpus = {1: "The game of life is a game of everlasting learning", 2: "The unexamined life is not worth living", 3: "Never stop learning"}
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary = myvocabulary, ngram_range = (1,3))
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus.values())
```

I want to calculate the tf-idf values for the two words `life` and `learning` for the 3 documents in `corpus`.

According to the article I am referring (see Table below) I should get the following values for my example.
[image: Target tf-idf scores]

However, the values I get from my code is completely different. Please help me find what is wrong in my code and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is that you should not restrict the vocabulary to just two words ('life', 'learning') before constructing the term frequency matrix. If you do that, all other words will be ignored and it will affect the term frequency counting.

There are also several other steps that need to be taken into account if one wants to get exactly the same numbers as in the example by using sklearn:

1. The features in the example are unigrams (single words) so I have
   set `ngram_range=(1,1)`.
2. The example uses different normalization than sklearn for the term
   frequency part (the term counts are normalized by document lengths
   in the example, whereas sklearn uses raw term counts by default).
   Because of this, I have counted and normalized the term frequencies
   separately before calculating the idf part.
3. The normalization in the example for the idf part is also not the
   default  for sklearn. This can be adjusted to match the example by
   setting `smooth_idf` to false.
4. Sklearn's vectorizers discard by default words with just one
   character, but such words are kept in the example. In the code
   below, I have modified `token_pattern` to allow also 1-character
   words.

The final tfidf matrix is obtained by multiplying the normalized counts by the idf vector.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import pandas as pd

corpus = {1: "The game of life is a game of everlasting learning", 2: "The unexamined life is not worth living", 3: "Never stop learning"}

cvect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w+\\b')
counts = cvect.fit_transform(corpus.values())
normalized_counts = normalize(counts, norm='l1', axis=1)

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w+\\b', smooth_idf=False)
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus.values())
new_tfs = normalized_counts.multiply(tfidf.idf_)

feature_names = tfidf.get_feature_names()
corpus_index = [n for n in corpus]
df = pd.DataFrame(new_tfs.T.todense(), index=feature_names, columns=corpus_index)

print(df.loc[['life', 'learning']])
```

However, in practice such modifications are rarely needed. One usually obtains good results just by using `TfidfVectorizer` directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your really great answer. However, in my real dataset I have bi-grams and trigrams. In such a case how this would have changed? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I actually tried with `ngram_range=(1,3)`. However, I am getting an error saying `ValueError: inconsistent shapes`

Comment: That `ValueError` comes probably if you have not set `ngram_range=(1,3)` both in `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfVectorizer`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer. However, it did not solve my problem completely. Because it does not capture my trigrams and bigrams correctly. That is one reason why I specifically mentioned `myvocabulary` in the code of my question :(

Comment: Hi, could you tell me, How to add the tf-idf values of particular word?